# How is an iPhone app named in the store?

Tags: iphone

Does apple set the name depending on the submitted binary or can the name be set by the developer?

I changed my display name of my app but didnt want to recreate the project to change the old name. So my .app name is not the name I want to give it in the app store.

Reason for this is that during the development of my app someone submitted an app with the same name.

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can change your iTunes App Name each time a new binary is submitted.
2. You can change your .app bundle name each time you upload a new binary (this is changed in the info.plist).
3. If the app is already in the App Store, you'll have to submit an update to change the app name(s).

In order to get the two to match, you need to upload a new compressed binary with an app name that at least resembles the iTunes App Name.  Since you can only show a small amount of the name on the Springboard (app launch view on the device), a lot of people abbreviate or shorten the name.

As an example, say you have an app called "My Brand New App" in iTunes (since this name can be longer).  Well, you'd wanna shorten that name or abbreviate it in the .app bundle to be something like "New App" or similar so the entire name would fit under the app icon without being truncated by the OS.

Comment: I have the correct bundle display name but my project name and thus my .app binary are different. Does apple use the bundle display name? there is a bundle name as well in the info.plist which currently just looks like ${PRODUCT_NAME}. If I test my app on the device it shows the correct name underneath the icon.

Comment: You can change project name in the project menu. There is a Rename menu item

Answer (score 2):

Since the app with name already exists there is no option then to choose new name.

**Name given to app in code(bundle icon name ..) is one which the user see when he installs application to his iPhone from app store.**

Name provided at the time of upload - **for ex: blah application** , **if user searches blah in app store it will show your application**.its **like tag** on which user searches the application.

hope this helps u.